# How to distinguish customer data?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am new for SharePoint 2013 app model. I am creating a provider-hosted app. My app will use Sql Azure to store data of each customer who installed my app will have their data, so how can I distinguish the data of them?

Any reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess each customer has a domain of its own, so my best bet would be to pass along a URL parameter when moderating stored content. You can easely get current URL from JavaScript `document.URL` or `window.location.href`.

Then you have separeted the customers, if you don't want to use sign-up/log-in functionality.

Comment: Sorry for this late but I don't get your answer until now. Yes, I agree with you. I cannot vote up your answer because I haven't enough reputation :(. Can you please let me know how can I vote up for you?